# Divide 4D cartesian grid for parallel processing

Tags: c++, algorithm, matlab, parallel-processing, combinatorics

I'm trying to compute some function(implemented as quite computing-costly iterative algorithm)  for all points on given grid of 4D input vectors(grid is Cartesian with equidistant points on each dimension, specified by segment `[a, b]` and number equally distant of points on this segment / constant step - for each dimension(4 total)). We can abstract away from "real-world" values, and consider grid as 4D-array with given dimensions(`[5, 4, 3, 7]` - 5x4x3x7 Cartesian grid) and using indexes on them - for referencing some slices/points.

My computing algorithm takes that vector(point on specified 4D-grid) as input and computes(probably during considerable time) some results(it doesn't matter what they are).

I need to parallelize program to speed up quite long process of computation on all grid's vertices. So i want to split input grid into sub-grids, with as near number of points on each grid as possible for balancing workload on different threads/processes.

Simplest solution is to divide grid on 1 chosen dimension - but problem is that, the number of slices on this isolated dimension may be less than number of "virtual computing devices"(different threads/processes in using - I will refer them as VCD). Number of VCD in use is non-constant, and is equal to number of sub-grids we need. So i need to use more dimensions for "splitting" - i think using 2-3 dimensions(due to specific input - we can assume some dimensions are greater than some value) produce enough of slices to divide between VCDs.

To explain better there's example. We have `[2, 2, 10, 7]` vector of 4D-grid sizes on each dimensions. Number of sub-grids is `20`. So we can't take one of dimensions and divide them into 20 segments, we got to combine them somehow. In this case we're lucky to notice that 2,3 dimensions are giving exactly 2x10 points = 20 VCDs. So we just split grid into `20` `[2, 1, 1, 7]` sub-grids(degenerated on 2,3 dimensions) and pass them to VCDs.

It becomes harder when none of dimensions products are divided by number of VCDs without a remainder, so we need to distribute it somehow/we need to use more dimensions together to split. For example, `[2, 3, 4, 5]` for VCD count = `11`.

So, question is - how to split given cartesian 4D-grid into N sub-grids(number of points on the grid is greater than N), probably using multiple dimensions simultaneously(one can assume complementary condition that some dimensions(3 at least) produce more slices than N - `dim[1] x dim[2] x dim[3]` > N)

I'm accepting answer in any language, but C-style pseudo-code is preferable.

**EDIT**: I realized that i don't need splitting grid at all, as Nico Schertler pointed out. I knew the trick with serializing index(thanks to matrix and heap implementations), but I was misguided by my "multi-dimensional" way of thinking. Also, i forgot to specify that computations on grid are completely independent. My original question that had to be solved was "How to divide 4D-grid for parallel processing" - building a serializing index and dividing sequence of points into segments based on it between processors is bright and simple solution(but it wasn't obvious for me). Also, this answer fits N-dimensional grid too. 
So my learnt lesson is - iteration(even parallel) needs only one dimension, so try to serialize.

Comment: If .NET is an option for you, you might enjoy [Load Balancing Partitioners](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997411.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just about calculating the values (and there are no dependencies), you don't have to work on the grid at all. Instead, serialize the grid into a 1D sequence and distribute this sequence evenly across processors.

The simplest serialization is:

```
i = x + dim[1] * (y + dim[2] * (z + dim[3] * w))
```

The inverse transformation is:

```
x = i % dim[1]
y = (i / dim[1]) % dim[2]
z = (i / dim[1] / dim[2]) % dim[3]
w = (i / dim[1] / dim[2] / dim[3])
```